# Xcode 10.2.1 and iOS 12.3 beta

Tags: ios, xcode

Updated Xcode to 10.2.1

Have a customer who is having an issue with my app on iOS 12.3 beta

Xcode 10.2.1 does not have a simulator for the 12.3 beta

How can I install iOS 12.3 beta as a simulator in Xcode?

Comment: You can’t. But perhaps you can install the 12.3 beta on _your_ device and test there.

Comment: @matt but what if I do not have the device.

As I have submitted a binary and it is rejected. They replied "App crashing on iPad running 12.3", but I do not have an iPad.
How I can test in this scenario?

Comment: Is this issue resolved ? I also got same issue for app rejection So , where will i find iPad running iOS 12.3 simulators? any help

Comment: I'm having the same issue! appstoreconnect rejected my app due to blank screen error on iPad running the ios 12.3.1. How to resolve this issue?

Comment: xcode10.3, out now, has ios 12.4 . So I think that means ipad 12.3 could be downloaded and added to it.

Answer (score 5):

Only *Apple* can provide new simulator iOS deployment versions to Xcode. For you to test your application on **iOS 12.3 Beta**, you will need to install your application on a physical device with that specific OS version or wait for *Apple* to introduce new iOS deployment version to Xcode.

**UPDATE (2019-08-09):**

What you could do is install beta software on your Mac (beta macOS version and beta Xcode version) and beta software on your iOS device (iPad or iPhone). Beta Xcode version usually always has upcoming iOS versions available for you to test, either on simulator or physical device. As of this update *iOS 13* and *iPadOS* are available for beta testing.

*Beta software can be found* [*here*](https://beta.apple.com/sp/betaprogram/).

Comment: Do they suppose that we developers will buy a device from each category to test?

Answer (score -1):

I am having the same issue w/app crashing on iPad running 12.3.1 on wifi.
The below has not helped me yet, maybe it will help you;
To find all simulators you can run => `xcrun simctl list devices`
   scroll to top to see available devices.
To run say iPad (6th Generation) => `react-native run-ios --simulator="iPad (6th generation)"`

Comment: Why would you run simulator with `react-native run-ios...`? You can use `xcrun` for it as well. Check this article - https://medium.com/xcblog/simctl-control-ios-simulators-from-command-line-78b9006a20dc.